# How do I fix a <Link> component error issue in React app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm experiencing an issue with the `<Link>` component from `react-router-dom`.

```
The above error occurred in the <Link> component:

    at LinkWithRef (http://localhost:3000/react-portfolio/static/js/bundle.js:64573:7)
    at button
    at http://localhost:3000/react-portfolio/static/js/bundle.js:3642:66
    at ButtonBase (http://localhost:3000/react-portfolio/static/js/bundle.js:9678:82)
    at http://localhost:3000/react-portfolio/static/js/bundle.js:3642:66
    at Button (http://localhost:3000/react-portfolio/static/js/bundle.js:9381:59)
    at div
    at div
    at http://localhost:3000/react-portfolio/static/js/bundle.js:3642:66
    at Toolbar (http://localhost:3000/react-portfolio/static/js/bundle.js:20646:82)
    at header
    at http://localhost:3000/react-portfolio/static/js/bundle.js:3642:66
    at Paper (http://localhost:3000/react-portfolio/static/js/bundle.js:18055:82)
    at http://localhost:3000/react-portfolio/static/js/bundle.js:3642:66
    at AppBar (http://localhost:3000/react-portfolio/static/js/bundle.js:8771:83)
    at div
    at http://localhost:3000/react-portfolio/static/js/bundle.js:3642:66
    at Box (http://localhost:3000/react-portfolio/static/js/bundle.js:23577:72)
    at div
    at Navbar (http://localhost:3000/react-portfolio/static/js/bundle.js:629:5)
    at div
    at PortfolioContainer (http://localhost:3000/react-portfolio/static/js/bundle.js:1060:88)
    at div
    at App
    at Router (http://localhost:3000/react-portfolio/static/js/bundle.js:66149:15)
    at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/react-portfolio/static/js/bundle.js:64481:5)

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
logCapturedError @ react-dom.development.js:18687
```

I'm guessing that this is located in my Navbar file somewhere, which you can see below:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import AppBar from '@mui/material/AppBar';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Toolbar from '@mui/material/Toolbar';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import IconButton from '@mui/material/IconButton';
import Menu from '@mui/material/Menu';
import MenuIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Menu';
import MenuItem from '@mui/material/MenuItem';

import '../styles/root.css';
import useWindowDimension from '../utils/windowDimensions';

import About from '../pages/About';
import Contact from '../pages/Contact';
import Portfolio from '../pages/Portfolio';
import Resume from '../pages/Resume';

export default function Navbar({ handlePageChange }) {
    const { height, width } = useWindowDimension();

    const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);
    const open = Boolean(anchorEl);
    const handleClick = (event) => {
        setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
    };

    const [anchorElNav, setAnchorElNav] = React.useState(null);
    const openNav = Boolean(anchorElNav);

    const handleOpenNavMenu = (event) => {
        setAnchorElNav(event.currentTarget);
    };

    const handleCloseNavMenu = () => {
        setAnchorElNav(null);
    }

    const handleClose = () => {
        setAnchorEl(null);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1, width: "100%" }} >
                <AppBar position="static" id="navbar">
                    <Toolbar>
                        <Typography
                            id="nav-logo"
                            variant="h6"
                            component="div"
                            sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}
                            fontFamily="reklame-script, sans-serif"
                            fontWeight="700"
                            fontStyle="normal"
                            fontSize="36px"
                            // onClick={() => handlePageChange('About')}
                        >
                            My Portfolio
                        </Typography>
                        {width >= 900
                            ?
                            <div
                                style={{ display: "flex", direction: "row", flexWrap: "wrap", justifyContent: "space-evenly", alignContent: "center", fontWeight: "bold" }}
                            >
                                <Button
                                    color="inherit"
                                    onClose={handleClose}
                                // onClick={() => handlePageChange('About')}
                                >
                                    <Link to={<About />}>
                                        About Me
                                    </Link>
                                </Button>
                                <Button
                                    color="inherit"
                                    onClose={handleClose}
                                // onClick={() => handlePageChange('Portfolio')}
                                >
                                    <Link to={<Portfolio />}>
                                        Portfolio
                                    </Link>
                                </Button>
                                <Button
                                    color="inherit"
                                    onClose={handleClose}
                                // onClick={() => handlePageChange('Contact')}
                                >
                                    <Link to={<Contact />}>
                                        Contact Me
                                    </Link>
                                </Button>
                                <Button
                                    color="inherit"
                                    onClose={handleClose}
                                // onClick={() => handlePageChange('Contact')}
                                >
                                    <Link to={<Resume />}>
                                        Resume
                                    </Link>
                                </Button>
                            </div>
                            :
                            // Mobile Hamburger Menu
                            <Box id='hamburger-menu' sx={{ flexGrow: 1, display: { xs: "flex", md: "none" }, justifyContent: "right" }}>
                                <IconButton
                                    id="menu-button"
                                    size="large"
                                    aria-controls={openNav ? 'menu-appbar' : undefined}
                                    aria-haspopup="true"
                                    aria-expanded={openNav ? 'true' : undefined}
                                    onClick={handleOpenNavMenu}
                                    color="inherit"
                                >
                                    <MenuIcon />
                                </IconButton>
                                <Menu
                                    id="menu-appbar"
                                    anchorEl={anchorElNav}
                                    anchorOrigin={{
                                        vertical: 'bottom',
                                        horizontal: 'right',
                                    }}
                                    transformOrigin={{
                                        vertical: 'top',
                                        horizontal: 'right',
                                    }}
                                    open={openNav}
                                    onClose={handleCloseNavMenu}
                                    sx={{
                                        display: { xs: 'block', md: 'none' },
                                    }}
                                >
                                    <div>
                                        <MenuItem className='mobileMenuItem' onClick={handleCloseNavMenu}>
                                            <Button color="inherit" >
                                                <Link style={{ textDecoration: "none", color: "black" }} to="/" onClose={handleClose}>
                                                    About Me
                                                </Link>
                                            </Button>
                                        </MenuItem>
                                        <MenuItem className='mobileMenuItem' onClick={handleCloseNavMenu}>
                                            <Button color="inherit" onClose={handleClose}>
                                                <Link style={{ textDecoration: "none", color: "black" }} to={"/portfolio"}>
                                                    Portfolio
                                                </Link>
                                            </Button>
                                        </MenuItem>
                                        <MenuItem className='mobileMenuItem' onClick={handleCloseNavMenu}>
                                            <Button color="inherit" onClose={handleClose}>
                                                <Link style={{ textDecoration: "none", color: "black" }} to="/contact">
                                                    Contact Me
                                                </Link>
                                            </Button>
                                        </MenuItem>
                                        <MenuItem className='mobileMenuItem' onClick={handleCloseNavMenu}>
                                            <Button color="inherit" onClose={handleClose}>
                                                <Link style={{ textDecoration: "none", color: "black" }} to="/resume">
                                                    Resume
                                                </Link>
                                            </Button>
                                        </MenuItem>
                                        <Menu
                                            id="basic-menu"
                                            anchorEl={anchorEl}
                                            open={open}
                                            MenuListProps={{
                                                'aria-labelledby': 'basic-button',
                                            }}
                                            onClick={handleClick}
                                            onClose={handleClose}
                                        >
                                        </Menu>
                                    </div>
                                </Menu>
                            </Box>
                        }
                    </Toolbar>
                </AppBar>
            </Box>
        </div>
    );
}
```

If it's not there, perhaps it's in my PortfolioContainer file?  This can be seen below.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import About from "../pages/About";
import Portfolio from "../pages/Portfolio";
import Contact from "../pages/Contact";
import Resume from "../pages/Resume";
import Navbar from "../components/Navbar";
import Footer from "../components/Footer";

export default function PortfolioContainer() {
    const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState('');

    const renderPage = () => {
        if (currentPage === '/') {
            return <About />
        }
        if (currentPage === '/resume') {
            return <Resume />;
        }
        if (currentPage === '/portfolio') {
            return <Portfolio />;
        }
        if (currentPage === '/contact') {
            return <Contact />;
        }
        // return <About />;
    };

    const handlePageChange = (page) => setCurrentPage(page);

    return (
        <div id="portfolioContainer">
            <Navbar currentPage={currentPage} handlePageChange={handlePageChange} />
            {renderPage()}
            <Footer />
        </div>
    );
};
```

Thank you in advance for any and all help!

Comment: The `Link` component is for linking to paths you are rendering routes for. You are using invalid `to` prop values. It seems you are also "reinventing the wheel" when it comes to what you are rendering. Please also narrow the focus of your post to a ***single*** specific issue.

Comment: Aloha, @DrewReese!  Oh, jeez.  I completely spaced and added incorrect `to` props like you said!  Thank you so much. >.< I've fixed the issue and now the navigation seems to be working.  For the other issue, I'll create a new question.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assumed you are useing react-router-dom@6.6.1 (latest version). "to" prop from  component expect a string but you provide the component. That's why you get cyclic object error. I took your code an defined a router in index.js file like this

```js
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";
import App from "./App";
import Resume from "./Resume";

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <App />
  },
  {
    path: "/resume",
    element: <Resume />
  }
]);

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
  </StrictMode>
);
```

and in my App.js file I used Link component like this

```
<Button
   color="inherit"
   onClose={handleClose}
 >
   <Link to="/resume">Resume</Link>
 </Button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, @ctrlSMDFK!  You and Drew Reese above solved my issue.  I can't believe I missed that.  Haha...  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The issue it seems is that you aren't using `react-router` to its fullest. The `Link` component should be specifying a `to` prop that matches a URL pathname that you are rendering a `Route` component for. `PortfolioContainer` should be rendering the routes you are trying to link to from the `Navbar` component.

Example:

PortfolioContainer

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import About from "../pages/About";
import Portfolio from "../pages/Portfolio";
import Contact from "../pages/Contact";
import Resume from "../pages/Resume";
import Navbar from "../components/Navbar";
import Footer from "../components/Footer";

export default function PortfolioContainer() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div id="portfolioContainer">
        <Navbar />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<About />} />
          <Route path="/resume" element={<Resume />} />
          <Route path="/portfolio" element={<Portfolio />} />
          <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact />} />
        </Routes>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};
```

Navbar

```
...
<Link to="/">
  About Me
</Link>
...
<Link to="/portfolio">
  Portfolio
</Link>
...
```